# The compiler optimized away a variable I need

Tags: c++, optimization

I have a class, AssetInstance:

```
#pragma once

#include "Asset.h"

#define GRAVITATIONAL_CONSTANT -2.45f

class AssetInstance
{
private:
    GLfloat maxX();
    GLfloat maxY();
    GLfloat maxZ();

    GLfloat minX();
    GLfloat minY();
    GLfloat minZ();

public:
    AssetInstance();
    ~AssetInstance();
    void updateBoundaries();
    void calculateMinAndMaxXYZ();
    glm::mat4 translate();
    glm::mat4 scale();
    void updatePosition();
    GLfloat timeInSeconds(long int time);
    GLfloat randomFloat();

    Asset* asset;
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 size;
    glm::vec3 materialColor;
    glm::vec3 materialSpecularColor;
    GLfloat materialShininess;
    long int lastTime;
    glm::vec3 velocity;
    glm::vec3 acceleration;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
    glm::vec3 max;
    glm::vec3 min;
};
```

and the function calculateMinAndMaxXYZZ() sets max.x, max.y, max.z to their max values and does the same thing with min and the minimum values.

However when I run my calculateMinxAndMaxXYZ() function, I get a message that my variable has been optimized away and not available... How do I stop this?

If I step into the class when the error is thrown, this is what it looks like

[image]

Comment: The address shown is 0x00000003 which more likely indicates that you invoked the method on a `AssetInstance *` that does not point to an instance of this object. Show us the code where you call the `calculateMinAndMaxXYZ()` method.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Whatever it is you'll want to use whatever flags are necessary to eliminate optimizations.

Comment: It looks like Microsoft Visual Studio 2013

Comment: @BobJarvis I don't think optimization is at play here, unless OP is doing something that relies on UB. Compilers are not allowed to optimize away instances of user-defined types completely, otherwise an aggressive compiler might attempt to optimize away instances of objects similar to `std::lock_guard`, and then where would we be?

Comment: You should probably clarify that the issue is you **cannot watch** the variable in the debugger. The way your question is worded, it sounds like you cannot access the variable _in your program_ because it has been optimized out. That would be a definite compiler bug, but what you are seeing is an entirely "normal" thing.

Comment: @Damon The stack trace indicates that there was a runtime exception, which is likely due to dereferencing the pointer 0x3. We really need to see the definition of `main()` to figure out why this is happening. It's most likely to be incorrect usage of a pointer. Until we have the definition of `main()` we can only speculate.

Comment: To verify that a variable has been optimized away, you will need to look at the assembly language listing.  *The truth is in the assembly language.*

Comment: @cdhowie: A compiler certainly is allowed to optimize away instances of user-defined types completely. But just like with any other optimization or code transformation (apart from copy elision), it needs to follow the as-if rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I never initialized the `vertices` vector in `AssetInstance` so I was trying to acces `vertices.at(0)` which didn't exist.